# Select2 is not rendered properly

Tags: jquery-select2

Im trying to integrate a basic select2 element to my project but cannot seem to find whats wrong.

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="myselect2" name="">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.myselect2').select2();
});
```

select2 is imported in the head of the project

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is jQuery included as well? Like in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-select2/info).

Comment: Thanks! Importing the script tags seem to fix the problem.

Comment: Great! Consider [adding a (self-)answer to the question and accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so it's marked as resolved.